# How can I make my custom webpart visible to the whole farm?

Tags: 2013, web-part, feature, scope

I am quite new to SharePoint. I am trying to update an Integration of SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I can add my custom webpart under the default site collection. But when I create a new site collection, the custom webpart is nowhere under the Insert->WebPart options. 
My integration is created as a app for sharepoint 2013 project. I checked the feature.xml generated, the scope is set to Site. which kind of explain why I can't see this in a new site collection. But I just can't change it to anything else. There are four options, "farm, sit, web, webapplication". But when I change it to another one. The deploy action complains that "The project item "XXX" cannot be deployed through a Feature with Farm scope.

Do anyone knows is there anyway I can deploy my custom webpart so it's visible to all the site collections?

Thank you very much
Gavin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified by Nadeem Yousuf in a previous answer, you need to activate the feature on the new site collection. 
If you require this to be activated on every site collection you create from here on out, you need to create an event receiver to activate this feature.

If the sites already exists, you can run a powershell command across your web application to activate this feature: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the feature in other site collections first. After that the webpart will be available.